# Matplotlib animate multiple great circles and update from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, updating

I've created a map and I am reading in a CSV of latitude and longitude coordinates into a Pandas DataFrame. I've been successful in plotting multiple great arcs using a 'for' loop after reading in the DataFrame.

I am now trying to animate the multiple great arcs. The reason for the animation is to live update the plot when the CSV is updated. I eventually will use a SQL table for the DataFrame rather than a CSV, but I wanted to get the animation portion working first.

I read and watched multiple tutorials on matplotlib and animation. I've read the source documentation and attempted to apply multiple examples. I've been able to successfully animate a single great arc but can't seem to expand the code to multiple arcs.

**Edit1: I want all great circle arcs from the file to be drawn on the map (I've got this part working). When a new set of latitude and longitude is added to the file I want it to update automatically within the same figure. I am trying to use this as a realtime display.**

**Edit2: I've paired down the code as much as possible. It is minimal with a basic map, a few long/lat coordinates in a data frame and my attempt to animate the lines. I had to keep a CSV input as it is the only way to verify that the map updates once the CSV is updated.

The CSV contains the following:

```
sourcelon  sourcelat   destlon  destlat
50.44    30.51     -80.84   35.22
52.52    13.4      -80.84   35.22
43.18    -22.97    -80.84   35.22
35.18    -22.97    -80.84   35.22
```

The arcs are being drawn, but are not being updated when the CSV is updated.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation

# create new figure, axes instances.
fig=plt.figure()


# setup mercator map projection.
plt.figure(figsize=(27, 20))
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines(color='r', linewidth=1.0)


def animate(i):
    df = pd.read_csv('c:/python/scripts/test2.csv', sep='\s*,\s*',header=0, encoding='ascii', engine='python'); df 


    for x,y,z,w in zip(df['sourcelon'], df['sourcelat'], df['destlon'], df['destlat']):
        line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,color='r')
        line, = plt.plot([],[])


ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems you are removing and deleting the greatcircle every time you create it. Just like `a = 5; del a; print(a)` - and wondering why `a` is gone.

Comment: Ah no. It's worse. You never actually call `animate`, so `x` and `y` are undefined. In general read and understand [mcve] and provide one in your question without any external data if you want help here.

Comment: I was trying to imitate the example here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403844/how-to-animate-matplotlibs-drawgreatcircle-function)

Comment: I wrote that example; but I cannot give an answer here because I don't know what exactly you are trying to do. It seems the data has several trajectories but at the end you only use one of them. What should happen to the others? And of course in the example the line is deleted *before*  the animation starts.

Comment: Understood, updating the post to more clearly state the issue.

Comment: Original post updated.

Comment: great, but not with a [mcve]. So what do you expect to happen now?

Comment: I've made it as minimal as possible while keeping it complete and verifiable. It is a basic map, a few long/lat coordinates in a data frame and my attempt to animate the lines. I had to keep a CSV input as it is the only way to verify that the map updates once the CSV is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. I am able to get the map to update when I add coordinates to the CSV. However, I cant remove them. I'll work on that as well.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation


# setup mercator map projection.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(27, 20))
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines(color='r', linewidth=1.0)



def animate(i):

    df = pd.read_csv('c:/python/scripts/test2.csv', sep='\s*,\s*',header=0, encoding='ascii', engine='python'); df 


    for x,y,z,w in zip(df['sourcelon'], df['sourcelat'], df['destlon'], df['destlat']):
        line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,color='r')



ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```